# Why is work done by a force is equal to $-\Delta(U)$?

Tags: forces, work, potential-energy

> Why is work done by a force is equal to $-\Delta(U)$ ?

Second fundamental theorem of calculus for line integral says that
$$\int_a^b \nabla f\cdot d(\vec{r}) = U(b) - U(a)$$ but in physics course they say 
$$\int_a^b \nabla f\cdot d(\vec{r}) = - U(b) + U(a)$$

So which one is true ?Probably both but how ?

By the way, are these potential function the same functions anyway ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In physics, conservative forces (forces which, when evaluated over a closed path, give you 0) can be represented by minus the gradient of some scalar function, which is called the $\textbf{potential}$.
$$ \mathbf{F} = -\mathbf{\nabla} V$$
(We are motivated to do this because of Stoke's Theorem)

The minus is a matter of equating the idea of this potential to that of potential energy, as described here: [Why is a conservative force defined as the negative gradient of a potential?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/188418/why-is-a-conservative-force-defined-as-the-negative-gradient-of-a-potential)
Now with this definition, we can see that if we consider work done, 
$$ W = \int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{x} = \int_{a}^{b} (-\nabla V) \cdot d\mathbf{x} = -(V(b) - V(a))= V(a) - V(b)$$
Hope this answers the question.

Note: I replaced the U in your question with a V, as it is a slightly more conventionally used notation in my experience.