# Why do physicists take the convention that a force field is the negative gradient of a scalar field?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, work, potential-energy, conventions

A conservative force is naturally the vector  gradient of a given scalar field . I don't know why the convention to put the negative sign in front of the gradient operator. 
Or is this just a misconception some of my professors had?

The gradient of 1/r is automatically in the negative r direction, so saying the force field is negative gradient is straight up wrong, if it were true the Earth would explode..

Edit:
It was brought to my attention that physicists like to define energies of classical systems to be negative. That answers the question of why they would take the negative gradient..

But really it just rises more questions than answers..
I thaught energy would almost always assumed to be non negative. 
Also energy is simply the hamiltonian of the lagrangian system.. so why even bother about some sign conventions in the definition of energy?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/188418/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 6):

The intuition is that potential is like height. It takes work to climb up; forces push you down. Another benefit is that with this sign, the potential is the potential energy, rather than its negative.

Comment: The gradient of 1/r is automatically in the negative r direction, so saying the force field is negative gradient is straight up wrong, if it were true the Earth would explode

Comment: @Schaurberger You've made a sign error. The _potential_ of the Earth is like $-1/r$. The force, which is the negative gradient of that, indeed points to smaller $r$.

Comment: @Schaurberger Alternatively, you could define the Schaurberger-potential of the Earth to be $1/r$, so that the force is $\nabla(1/r)$, which also points to smaller $r$. Obviously, both ways are going to give you the same force, because they differ by two minus signs.

Comment: Ok so that is the convention. That the potential is actually negative. And it makes sense since for gravitational potential  makes it so that the higher it is the bigger potential..

Comment: It seems rather unnatural to assume a negative energy for a classical system.

Comment: @Schaurberger First of all, the sign of the potential energy by itself doesn't really mean anything - one can always arbitrarily shift the expression for the potential by any constant value and the physics won't change, because the physics only depends on how the potential _changes_ across space. That said, the particular case of the $-1/r$ potential goes infinitely negative because it takes an _input_ of energy to disassemble the system, this input can get arbitrarily large, and the disassembled system has a finite energy (we typically assume this to be zero, but it doesn't have to be).

Comment: I disagree. Work you have to do to disassemble the system is negative since the force is opposite to displacement..

Comment: @Schaurberger The force that _you_ exert _on_ the system when you disassemble it is in the same direction as displacement, so the work done _on_ the system is positive. The sign of the work that is exerted _by_ the system is negative, because the gravitational force acts opposite to the displacement. Once again, this is another convention, which is specified by clarifying whether you're talking about work done _on_ the system or work done _by_ the system.

Comment: @Schaurberger The two statements are logically consistent with each other, despite being opposite in sign, because they are talking about an energy flow in opposite directions. The disassembler is giving a positive amount of energy to the system (hence, positive work is being done _on_ the system _by_ the disassembler), while the system is taking energy from its environment, or equivalently, is giving a negative amount of energy to its environment (hence, negative work is being done _by_ the system _on_ its environment).

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, take the Lagrangian of a one-dimensional point subject to some potential $V(x)$:

$$L = \frac12 m \dot x^2 - V(x).$$

Taking the variation of the action, we have,

$$\delta S = \int \mathrm dt \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\delta x + \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}\delta \dot x\right)$$

and noting that $\delta \dot x = \partial_t(\delta x)$, we can apply integration by parts,

$$\delta S = \int \mathrm dt \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}- \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x} \right)\delta x = 0$$

which we demand to be zero, and assume the boundary term vanishes. Plugging in our expression for the Lagrangian, we have,

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x} = m\ddot x = \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}.$$

We identify $m\ddot x$ as the force, so the (one-dimensional) gradient of $V$ gives us the force, with a minus sign which is not arbitrary.

The minus sign in $L$ is by the definition - kinetic minus potential energies. The minus sign in the integral comes from the integration by parts rule, not forcefully put in.

Comment: "For simplicity, take the Lagrangian..." I think you're overestimating the OP's physics background, but maybe you know that and want to provide an answer for a different audience.

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy The OP is doing vector calculus, so in an undergraduate physics program, he should have done Lagrangian mechanics or will be doing it in the very near future.

Answer (score 1):

So that the mechanical energy may be defined as kinetic plus potential and be conserved. Otherwise it would be kinetic minus potential that's conserved and that's silly because how is it that *subtracting* an energy from another gives you the *total* mechanical energy?

Comment: how you ask? Well, the answer is just like that lol...

Comment: Energy fundamentally is a hamiltonian, a time symmetry of the lagrangian system. And yes of course it comes as a substraction of two terms..

Comment: @Schaurberger I don't understand what you're trying to convey.

Comment: It's just very confusing. First of all energy need not be conserved in general.. isnt giving an arbitrary constat to energy choosing a gauge?

Comment: You're right, it needn't be conserved in general, but when it is, defining $E = T + V$ makes more sense than $E = T - V$.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking one can view it as wanting a potential function to look like a landscape where a ball will tend to roll “downhill,” if that helps. This means that the force should be in the direction of greatest decrease of potential energy, which is $-\nabla U$.

There is nothing wrong with the opposite sign convention; it is merely unintuitive because in the presence of drag things would tend towards potential maximums rather than minimums, and so we would call it something other than “potential” energy (indicating that it has the *potential* to be used for work): perhaps “wasted” or “spent” energy.

Comment: Yea that makes sense. I just think that intuitive or not , conventions have no place in physics. Physics is about how nature works not about what pleases our intuition. Especially when introduction of negative energy is not very natural in the context of general relativity because it would produce negative curvature.